# General version of Hoeffding's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

I know that if we have $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ independant random variables such that $\left|X_{i}-\mathbb{E}(X_{i})\right| \leq M \;$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$ then if we define $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\;$ we have for all $a>0$:

$$\mathbb{P}(X-\mathbb{E}(X)\geq a)\leq \exp\left(\frac{-a^{2}}{2nM^{2}}\right).$$

How can I derive from that the general version that says that:

$$\mathbb{P}(\left|X-\mathbb{E}(X)\right|\geq a)\leq2\cdot \exp\left(\frac{-a^{2}}{2nM^{2}}\right)?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the fact you know to $X'_i:=-X_i$, which satisfies the same assumptions: this gives
$$
\mathbb{P}(-X+\mathbb{E}(X)\geq a)\leqslant \exp\left(\frac{-a^{2}}{2nM^{2}}\right)
$$
or in other words,
$$
\mathbb{P}( X- \mathbb{E}(X)\leqslant  -a)\leqslant \exp\left(\frac{-a^{2}}{2nM^{2}}\right).
$$
Now, the event $\left\{\left|X-\mathbb{E}(X)\right|\geq a\right\}$ is the union of the events $A:=\left\{ X-\mathbb{E}(X) \geq a\right\}$ and $B:=\left\{ X-\mathbb{E}(X)\leqslant -a\right\}$; bound the probability using of $\left\{\left|X-\mathbb{E}(X)\right|\geq a\right\}$ by the sum of probabilities of the   events $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I think he asks for a proof of $\mathbb{P}(X-\mathbb{E}(X)\geq a)\leq exp\left(\frac{-a^{2}}{2nM^{2}}\right)$ given $\mathbb{P}(\left|X-\mathbb{E}(X)\right|\geq a)\leq2\cdot exp\left(\frac{-a^{2}}{2nM^{2}}\right)$, I also think it is impossible if for instance $X_i$ takes support on $\{-1,M\}$ and averages to $0$ for instance, however the statement might still be true on it's own.

Comment: @P.Quinton

He actually got me right, sorry for my lousy English.